# getting not a usable net address error , in between a mlcp job run

Tags: marklogic-10, mlcp

we are running a mlcp job to redact data from one server to other and the whole process take 2 days time to complete but now after running to 10 hours, it is giving

`'Default provider - Not a usable net address: outputhost:8000 ERROR LocalJobRunner:450 - Error committing task: null'` error.

I am not able to understand why we are getting this error as earlier it is working fine.

marklogic version: 10.0.3, mlcp version: 10.0.4